# How align gpx track with leaflet map Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet, openstreetmap, gpx

I have a problem with my gpx track on leaflet map.
My track is displayed on the map but not aligned with road.
I use this library to display the track :
https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx
I don't kwo if the library have a problem or if i configure my leaflet map with wrong data.
I make the website with laravel

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile-cyclosm.openstreetmap.fr/cyclosm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    attribution: '<a href="https://github.com/cyclosm/cyclosm-cartocss-style/releases" title="CyclOSM - Open Bicycle render">CyclOSM</a> | Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: This library probably just displays your track. Aligning a GPX track with a road is a significantly more complex problem and requires a "map matching" algorithm. Search for "map matching" APIs if you really need this.

Comment: See e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/map-matching-links-and-ideas

Comment: I make the website with laravel and i discoverd that laravel have a problem with openstreetmap